# What's the proper way to use Docker multi-stage builds to copy a package installed with apt?

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, apt

I have `apt-get -y install ffmpeg --no-install-recommends` in my dockerfile and it's taking up more than half the image size (500MB). I read somewhere that I can try using Docker multi-stage build to reduce the file size.

Am I supposed to do something like:

```
FROM node:20.9.0-slim
RUN apt-get -y update \
  && apt-get -y install ffmpeg --no-install-recommends \
  && apt-get clean

FROM node:20.9.0-slim
COPY --from=0 /usr/bin/ffmpeg
COPY --from=0 /usr/bin/ffplay
COPY --from=0 /usr/share/ffmpeg/ffprobe.xsd
COPY --from=0 /usr/share/lintian/overrides/ffmpeg
```

I ran `dpkg -L ffmpeg` to see that ffmpeg has ~30 files. Am I supposed to copy over all of the files or is just `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` enough? If I have to copy all of them, it seems like it'll break easily.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically know what the individual files in a package are, what they do, and why you need them, you can't really get a smaller installation than what `apt-get install --no-install-recommends` gives you.  There aren't reliable tricks you can do with multi-stage builds to only install part of the package.

Looking at the [Debian package page for `ffmpeg`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/ffmpeg) that package itself is only about 2 MB.  The man pages normally get suppressed, but you might need a half-dozen files in `/usr/share/ffmpeg`.  The bigger problem is that `ffmpeg` depends on what looks like 9 different shared-library packages, and if you don't install them then the binaries presumably won't run.  [`libavcodec59`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/libavcodec59) is itself largish (~14 MB) and has very many dependencies; I'm guessing some of this is where the massive image size comes from.

The case where multi-stage builds can help are if you need some tool as part of building your image, but don't need that tool to actually run it.  In a Node context, if you have packages with C extensions, you might need a C compiler but only to run `npm install`.  (This is much more common in Python.)  In a compiled language like Go, you don't need the compiler to run the program, so you can use a first build stage to compile the application and then a second stage that only copies the built application, but not the tools that created it.  Since in this case the build system is under your control, you probably know what all the required files are, and you can make sure the parts you need wind up in the final image.